# Migrate Pipelines and files from one Azure DevOp services to another Azure DevOp services

Tags: azure-devops-services

First question: We need a way to migrate all the pipelines from the source environment to a new target environment. We also need to do this for the files. This is not an issue with the Azure DevOps server but having issued another one by one when using Azure DevOps Services to Azure DevOps Services.

Second: There is no guidance for best security governance for RBAC/AD and setting up organizations and projects to actually follow for a medium-sized development group that is migrating from another organization.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi @Kenneth P Barnes, please state the problem clearly, especially for the first question. Layout the context, what is needed, what errors you are getting. Share some detail so people can understand and give meaningful help.

Comment: I am attempting to migrate Azure DevOps Services which I will say is "A company" from one organization to another Azure DevOps Sevices, which will call "B company". I would like to clone everything that is A-company to B-company without having to do one manually. Plus I need to know what security to have accessed this so that this can be done. I can't even clone or migrate one as my security is limited.  Remember this is Azure DevOps Services to Azure DevOps Services which also has been a headache, to say the least. Appreciate any insight in advance

Comment: I am also trying to copy all the file too but this has been somewhat daunting too.. Please help